# Using Null Values in Raster To NumPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, numpy, array, null

I am trying a convert a raster dataset [a simple 4 x 4] into a numpy array using `RasterToNumPyArray`. Here is my sample raster dataset:

[image: Sample Raster Dataset]

`RasterToNumPyArray` however, returns zero for `Null` values:

```
inRaster = "Slope_NULL"

# Create a Raster Object and get its lowerleft
aRObject = arcpy.Raster(inRaster)
lowerLeft = aRObject.extent.lowerLeft

print aRObject.noDataValue

# Create a numpy array of the Raster Object
anArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(aRObject) 
print anArray
```

and I get:

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way that I could get `None` or `NaN` instead of zero in my array?

I know I can change the Nodata to a value using `nodata_to_value`, however, `RasterToNumPyArray` syntax is explaining that the default value is `None`, and it is important for me to have `None` and not zeros in my array.

How can I have `None` or `NaN` [I am not sure which one is better supported in numpy] in my array?

Comment: there is a nodata parameter in RasterToNumpy, discussed here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/217775/46073

Comment: @AndreasMüller Yes, it has a parameter "nodata_to_value" which convert nodata to a value. If it is not set it converts nodata to zero as I showed in my example.

Comment: @Hornbydd Would you please take a look at this question?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is NAN in Numpy module:

```
import numpy as np
arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(inRaster, nodata_to_value= np.NAN)
```

Also see for [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html) for other constants defined in Numpy.